# How to get a list of words and lines in a two dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, text

I have a text file of full of sentences and I am trying to get the individual words split up into a two dimensional array in java. The rows of the array correspond to the lines of the text, and the columns are the individual words. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't gather much from this. Could you please elaborate? Maybe paste some relevant code from what you have tried? Rows correspond to lines, and columns to words..just didn't get the exact requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a few things:

- a [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html), which has the method  `public String readLine()`
  to read a line from the file.
- the method `public String[] split(String regex)` from `String` class that can split a string with specified regular expression and already place single strings in an array.
- iterate over the file, read a line as long as there are available, split the line, and store all of them in a list
- convert the list to an array and you are done